# Find an element in List of List, c#

Tags: c#

I have a list of lists as below:

`List<List <T> > userList`

`Class T { string uniqueidentifier, string param2, int param2}`

I have a uniqueidentifier and i need to find the element T in the list that has the same 'uniqueidentifier' value.

I can do it using two 'foreach' loops. This does not seem to be nice way doing things. I guess there should be some inbuilt method like 'Find' that does the same thing and is highly optimized.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Find` is not optimized at all -- it performs a linear search, since that's the only thing that makes sense on an unsorted list.  If you are looking at a nicer way to write it, you could use LINQ:

```
var element = (from sublist in userList
               from item in sublist
               where item.uniqueidentifier == someid
               select item).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Super cool. Wonderful. I am really amazed by power of Linq. Can you point me to some good LINQ resources?

Answer (score 2):

Without indexing/hashing a "highly optimized" find won't help. Your best bet is change the storage method of your data, such as a tree.

Without changing the storage mechanism, if you are on a multi-core system parallelize the search.

Comment: Yes i would have to try a different storage method. But I did find the answer by cdhowie, using LINQ quite useful. It seems to reasonably fast but I haven't really tried on large lists. would changing data storage to tree be faster than LINQ ?

Comment: Under the covers LINQ won't be magical and do anything differently. The only thing it would do is delay the use of your result, or in other words lazy loading the result until you used it. cdhowie was very careful to say "nicer way to write it" instead of "performs a faster search"

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you change the outer list to a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx), then you can find the inner list with its unique identifier.

```
     Dictionary<string, List<T>> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string,List<T>>();
     myDictionary["1"] = innerList;
     List<T> list = myDictionary["1"]; //find list with unique id "1"
```

Comment: the unique identifier is of the item, not of the inner list. This means an innerList has more than one unique identifiers. as many as the items it contains

Comment: Clean and straight forward idea ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var query =
    from ts in userList
    from t in ts
    where t.uniqueidentifier == uniqueidentifier
    select t;

var user = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

not 100% if this will work..

```
var match = userList.Where(x=> x.Any(y=>y.uniqueidentifier = "blah"));
```

Comment: This will find the inner list that contains the item with that identifier; it will not find the item itself.

Comment: @cdhowie, yeah you're right, could easily get it, but that would require searching the list again, which would be inefficient, definately not a good solution!

Comment: That's why you want to use `SelectMany` instead.  See my answer -- the compiled code will use `SelectMany` to flatten the nested list structure into one long sequence of elements.

Comment: @cdhowie: ah thanks, although i've written many queries like the one in your answer, i wasn't aware of the lamdba form for it.